# Question regarding a coinflip game (Probability)

Tags: probability

Question is as follow:

> $(a)$ We are playing a game with a coin. The coin is tossed until someone reaches $5$ of their face. I.e, $5$ Heads. That person wins. I am going to toss the coin once then let you decide what you want to be. What is your probability of winning. (To make this clear if I toss the coin first, its a head then you decide to be heads you now only need $4$ more heads to win whereas I still need $5$ tails).

My approach for part $(a):$

The game is decided when it reaches $4$ Heads or $5$ Tails. Consider the series of $9$ coin flips, which is the maximum amount of coin flip for the game. Actually, $8$ coin flips will be suffice to conclude the game. Among the $2^8$ combination for the $8$ coin flips, Tails will only win if the number of Tails in the $8$ sequences is $\geq 5$. Therefore the probability for Tails to win will be $\frac{1+8+28+56}{2^8} = \frac{93}{256}$. Hence, the probability of Head winning (the matter of interest) = $1 - \frac{93}{256} = \frac{163}{256}$.

> $(b)$ Now instead of coins we play the same game with cards. So you must select a suit (Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs) and we turn over cards (without replacement) until someone has seen $5$ of their suit. Same thing. Now I let you decide, would you like to pick your suit right away, after I show $1$ card, or after I show $2$ cards. Which of these $3$ options gives you the best chance of winning.

For part $(b),$ I don't have much idea in getting a rigorous calculation for the answer. But just intuitive guess, I will say after showing $1$ cards, it will gives the best chance of winning. Because we may just choose whatever suit it appears. If choosing upfront, it will be just a random guess with a chance of $\frac{1}{4}$; Having $1$ card shown will be the same as the coin version, will give a slight advantage; while having $2$ cards shown might

- showing $2$ cards of the same suit, which will happen with a probability of $\frac{12}{51}$, and gives a slightly greater advantage.
- showing two cards of different suit, with a probability of $\frac{39}{51}$, which will give the second suit the same advantage as the first suit. So an intuitive guess from me will be after $1$ card.

Would love to know whether there is more intuitive answer for the two parts (especially if there is a simple way for calculating part $(b)$).

Answer (score 1):

The first part seem correct.

Regarding the second, there is a far easier way to get the answer than doing a lot of computations. Let's assume that picking your suit before knowing anything is best. Then, if the first card is revealed, it is still possible to make the exact same choice and to get the exact same result. However, seeing the first card gives you information that could be used to choose better. Therefore, choosing after seeing one card is at least as good as choosing without seeing any.

You can make a similar reasoning to justify that choosing after seeing two cards is also at least as good as choosing after seeing one card, making it the best overall option.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your reasoning on the second part. Would you mind elaborate a little more?

Comment: The idea is that having extra information cannot prevent you from making the decision you would have made without that information. So having extra information is always beneficial, which makes the last option the best.

Comment: You ignored the decision component of the opponent. So the second part analysis is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x, y)$ denote the probability of winning for you. Your solution for the first part looks correct. To compute the solution for the second part, note the following facts:
$$P(12, 13) = \frac{12}{25} P(11, 13) + \frac{13}{25} P(12, 12) \leftarrow 0.5 \text{ due to symmetry}$$
$$P(11, 13) > 0.5$$
Then you can calculate:
$$P(12, 13) - \frac{12}{51}P(11, 13) - \frac{39}{51}P(12, 12) = \frac{12 \times 51 - 12 \times 25}{25 \times 51} P(11, 13) + \frac{13 \times 51 - 39 \times 25}{25 \times 51 \times 2} = \frac{312}{1275} \left(P(11, 13) - \frac{1}{2}\right) > 0$$
So you should choose to reveal only 1 card.